# How to check if the page itself had a error loading, with API 23?

Tags: java, android, webview

I've tried to check if the page itself, and not the secondary resources, had problems with loading, by overriding `onReceivedError` in my WebView.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    //...

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {

        //do something with error.getErrorCode()

    }

    //...
});
```

However, once the page load is completed, even if the page seems to have been loaded correctly sometimes I get junk calls of `onReceivedError`, and thus unable to determine if the page hasn't loaded actually (e.g., cache miss of the page itself).

What can I do about it?

Comment: I assume I could have missed some duplicate posts addressing this problem. Or there's no sense to have this as a separate Q&A and I should have picked an existing question on a more broad problem (not exactly API 23) to post the answer to. Or it's just too trivial to be a separate Q&A (can't judge about that though, not an experienced developer in this area). Please comment then, and I'll remove the Q&A. I've just found that searching doesn't provide me with a solution and tried to do that myself (seems that I've succeeded).

Answer (score 0):

Since API 23, this method has been modified and now is called whenever anything, even secondary resources (i.e., images / stylesheets / scripts) have got errors loading.

The fix is to check whether the primary URL is equal to the Requested URL, and only then perform any actions.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    //...

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {

        if(request.getUrl().toString().equals(myWebView.getUrl())){
             //that's the page that throws the error
        }

    }

    //...
});
```